# What is a library in Java and where can I find the standard libraries in Java?

Tags: java

I hear the term of standard libraries a lot in Java. Is a library just a collection of packages, which is indirectly a collection of classes. So would that make a library a collection of classes? What makes a library different from a standard library?

I do see this answer on this link below where they say packages and standard library are the same thing. [Where can I find a list of the Java Standard libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868825/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-the-java-standard-libraries)

But this link here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html tells me that packages and libraries are a different thing. So I guess my question now also is where can I find this standard library, and are there multiple standard libraries or are there just one?

Comment: You should check out this Q&A: [Class vs package vs module vs component vs container vs service vs platform in Java world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157377). The question itself includes many links. You should also look at its linked/related questions (right side of the page).

Answer (score 0):

It's really great that you're trying to understand the specifics of the language! From my understanding:

- The standard library holds the individual packages provided by Oracle -- so your
  understanding about the standard library is correct, there is only 1.
- You, as a developer, can also create your own Java library with packages. This
  is what leads to multiple 'libraries'.

Answer (score 0):

**The word package has a lot meanings in Java programming.**

It can mean:
The folder where the class file "MyClass.java" is stored.
or
The jar file where the library is store - which is packaged as a jar file.

Here is a list of standard libraries/packages in Java 8:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-summary.html

Read more about packages here:
[What's the difference between "package" and "module"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680883/whats-the-difference-between-package-and-module)